# Get values of changed input boxes

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-data

I'm trying to get the **changed values** in a div and display them on console and here is the code I have so far but it is not displaying anything.

```
    <div id="mainDiv">
        <input type="text" id="myID" value="1" />
        <input type="text" id="myID" value="2" />
        <input type="text" id="myID" value="3" />
        <input type="text" id="myID" value="4" />
        <input type="text" id="myID" value="5" />
    </div>

    <button id="getText">Submit</button>
```

Here is my JS function

```
    $('#mainDiv input[type="text"]').each(function () {
        $(this).data('somevalue', $(this).val());
    });


    $('#getText').click(function () {
        var msg = 'You haven\'t saved your changes.';
        var isTrue = false;

        $('#mainDiv input[type="text"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).data('somevalue') != $(this).val()) {
                isTrue = true;
                // Display only changed items on console ...
            }
        });

        if (isTrue == true) {
            return msg;
        }
    });
```

The code is not working.

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/JQPurfect/xcej3rav/ if that helps.

Comment: Your code works fine, you just are not outputting the values: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/xcej3rav/4/

Comment: ***The code is not working.*** Exactly what do you mean by this?

Comment: What do you mean not working. U need to display the msg to the console.log(msg) to see if it's not working

Comment: You probably want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/xcej3rav/5/

Answer (score 1):

To get check that value chenged you can compare current `value` property with `value` attribute:

```
$('#mainDiv input[type="text"]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('value') != this.value) {
        isTrue = true;
        // Display only changed items on console ...
        console.log(this.value)
    }
});
```

In this case you don't even have to remember anything in data attributes. It works because value *attribute* holds the default value input initially had. Whenever you change value of the input, its `value` property updates, however attribute stays the same it was (unless it's explicitly updated).

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xcej3rav/3/

Comment: Whereas this is helpful, I doubt it is the answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: @PeterKA Why do you think this is not the answer OP's looking for?

Comment: His jsfiddle produces the same result as yours: all he is missing is the `console.log()` line; I could be wrong.

Comment: Hm, looks like you are right, missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
$(this).data('somevalue', $(this).val());
```

to this:

```
$(this).attr('data-somevalue', $(this).val());
```

Seems to do the trick.

Comment: This has the same effect as the OP's and `.data()` is more preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are trying to return a message from a click handler, but the return value of the click handler isn't going anywhere.  If you put the message into a div or some other entity on the page you would see that the changes are being seen.
As far as I understand, the click() method doesn't have any useful return value.